# I want to disable all the dates except specific dates in daterangepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, daterangepicker

Currently I am using daterangepicker (http://www.daterangepicker.com/) and I want to disable all the dates except some specific dates with option isInvalidDate.Here is my example code:-

```
isInvalidDate: function (date) {

           return ["2017/01/12","2017/01/28"].indexOf(formatted) > -1;

}
```

I am not able to find the solution. Please let me know if body knows about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set 
minDate:
to specific date .It will disable past dates and 
maxDate:next day date.. it will disable future dates

```
$('#demo').daterangepicker({
"startDate": "01/11/2017",
"endDate": "01/17/2017",
"minDate": "01/19/2017",
"maxDate": "01/20/2017"
}, function(start, end, label) {
console.log("New date range selected: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + '  to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' (predefined range: ' + label + ')");
});
```

in above example 19-jan-2017 is only date enable all others are disabled

Comment: No its not my requirement, I am using "ranges" option in daterangepicker and I want to enable only those dates.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution :)
here is the code.

```
isInvalidDate: function (date) {

 var dateArray = ["2017/01/12","2017/01/28"];
 return dateArray.indexOf(formatted) < false;

}
```